# What was Sloth's handicap?

Tags: character, the-goonies

In The Goonies, Sloth was the unwanted son of Mama Fratelli and the hero at the end of the story.

He had an obvious facial deformity, but he was also really strong, could speak and capable of love.

He seemed to lack some intelligence; but that could have been from the way he was raised (secluded), or dropped as a child (Mama admits to doing this at least twice; but we get the impression it was more) or maybe both.

If Chunk and Chunk's mom took Sloth to the doctor the day after they were rescued, what diagnose would he receive?

In other words, was he mentally handicapped or just deformed?  And what could cause that kind of deformation?

Comment: I believe Sloth to have Apert Syndrome.

Comment: I read the first line as "Sloth was the son of (Mama Fratelli and the hero)" ... and was like ummm, nooooooo.

Answer (score 15):

It is the direct result of him being dropped by Ma Fratelli when he was an infant. I believe it's alluded to in the movie itself, and by alluded to, I mean *explicitly stated* in one scene.

If you want a diagnosis, it's usually referred to as infant brain injury. It includes dropping, shaken baby syndrome, etc.

In the movie it is the cause of both his physical deformity as well as his mental handicap, his later treatment by the Fratellis most likely caused the emotional trauma he exhibits later in the film.

Answer (score -1):

It might be [Craniosynostosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craniosynostosis) .

As an infant his soft spots fused early causing cranio facial deformities.